# Assembling 32bit Assembly on 64bit Machine

Tags: assembly

I have an assembly source file which I wish to assemble, however it uses 32bit registers on the stack, of which is no longer acceptable on my 64bit machine.  I used `as magic.s -o magic.o --32` to generate my object file (this worked fine), but when using `ld magic.o -o magic` to link it I get the error `i386 input file magic.s is incompatible with i386 86/64 output.`  Is there any way around this?

If I have to modify the source code and replace the registers which are pushed onto the stack, like `%eax` to `%rax`, for example, is there anything I should worry about, like specifying different sizes?  Or could I just substitute the register names for their 64bit counterparts.  Naturally I'd experiment this myself, but I'd like to know about how 64bit registers size relates to 32bit.

Comment: Try `ld magic.o -o magic -m elf_i386`.

Comment: If you have strings in your `.data` and are calculating the length with `$ - label` this will not work if you have more than string in `.data`. This gets a lot of people on the transition. See [**Chapter 1 – String Length**](http://www.int80h.org/strlen/) for one approach that will work for finding length on x86_64.  Also, all your syscall numbers are different, see `/usr/include/asm/unistd_64.h`

Comment: Thank you for the answers.  Using the elf_i386 emulation seems to have worked.  What exactly does elf stand for?